# Stress-ng: What is the target object file created after doing a "make" in the source files directory?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, x86-64, stress-testing

What is the target object file created after doing a "make" in the source files directory? 
I tried to make from the directory containing .c files for stress-ng. 
I didn't see any target object file to do a ./target
**How can I execute stress-ng?**

Comment: Can you post your makefile or any related code ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of stress-ng. To get a full build of stress-ng with all the features you need to also install the following packages:

- zlib1g-dev
- libbsd-dev
- libattr1-dev
- libkeyutils-dev
- libapparmor-dev
- libaio-dev
- libcap-dev

To build from source:

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/cking/stress-ng
cd stress-ng
make clean
make
```

and you can run it from the directory where it has been built using:

```
./stress-ng
```

or install it using:

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: Is this build successful in amd64architecture? Could this be cross compiled to MIPS architecture with a toolchain

Comment: After installing the packages mentioned, I tried ./stress-ng from stress-ng directory. I got an error saying " -bash: ./stress-ng: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error". The architecture of the system is x86_64

Comment: Without adding toolchain when I followed the steps, got an error saying christo@teltvm1562x:~/postutility/stress-ng$ ./stress-ng 
stress-ng: info:  [28907] defaulting to a 86400 second (1 day, 0.00 secs) run per stressor
stress-ng: error: [28907] No stress workers
How to solve this

Comment: You need to specify the stressor type when running stress-ng, e.g. stress-ng --cpu 1